# Two methods in a loop

Tags: android

```
private void cameraOn() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera = Camera.open();
             parameters = camera.getParameters();
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
private void cameraOff() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
             camera.setParameters(parameters);
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
        }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent finis = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(finis, 0);
        }
```

I have these two methods and the button, and I want both methods work in a loop every second each, untill I press the botton for break the loop and go to another screen. These methods are for switch on and off the flash. So I want the flash blinking all the time until I press the button. I tried with threads but Im not able to do every method work just for one second, so I hope someone can help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry if I explained bad, I mean, I tried with threads but I'm not able to do the first method work just for one second and the second one second as well

Comment: No, with handlers i didnt try

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's some kind if timer object you could use, but I would do something like:

```
long lastTime = 0;
boolean torchIsOn = false;

long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (currentTime - lastTime >= 1000) {
    if (torchIsOn) {
        cameraOff();
        torchIsOn = false;
    } else {
        cameraOn();
        torchIsOn = true;
    }
    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

That's just from the top of my head, so hopefully that works. ;)

Comment: Oh, and obviously you'd want to put that in a thread or while loop that keeps going until you press the button. In the button's onClickListener you would either stop the thread or set some boolean to stop the loop.